# Hide a layout in other gridview rows and show only on clicked position

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I have a gridview. That gridview contains an imageview and a layout. On click of the imageview, I am setting the layout background as black with some alpha. Now the problem is, suppose I set background on position 2 by clicking imageview at position 2. Now when I click the imageview at position 4, the layout at position 4 gets alpha background but the problem is that the layout at position 2 still has that alpha background. What I want is that all other layouts should set to default white and only the clicked position should have that alpha background. Whats the solution for this.?

**Main Gridview:**

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right">
</GridView>
```

**Row Item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_small">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_foregroundcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainLay_Alpha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_down_icon" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**GridView Adapter:**

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_product_item, null, true);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mainLay_Alpha);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mainLay);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(productMoreOptOverlayId != null && productMoreOptOverlayId.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    layout.setBackground
                else
                    layout.removeBackground
            }
        });



        return rowView;

    };
```

Comment: show some code so it will better to help you

Comment: Actually I didnt include the code because its a simple gridview with an adapter. Will update the code too.

Comment: at a time you want last selected grid background and other are white so you have written some code for setting background and i think you implemented adapter also so share that code